# Facebook sdk login appears whenever UITable is used

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I have implemented Facebook into my app but now I find that whenever I try using a UITableView  elsewhere, the Facebook Login screen appears in the view instead and it is covering up the table that should be there. It is like the login screen functionality is in the background (I cannot  interact with the login screen) but it is displayed in the foreground?

I implemented everything as the tutorial on fb shows... Including what is needed in the app delegate. If anyone knows what code I need to modify within the Facebook sdk it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

P.S. If you would like the code... I can post its just there is a quite a bit of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the UITableWhite and it seems to cover up the Facebook